# The current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, settings.settings

I'm trying to use a settings file to store the user preferences when he/she logins on the application.

I defined them as user (scope) but I am getting

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The current configuration system does not support user-scoped settings.`

What may be a good solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

User-scoped settings are indeed not supported for a Web application. And they wouldn't work, User settings would have to be saved under the `Users\<username>\...` folder on the server.

You have a wide choice of web techniques:

- persistent cookies
- ASP.NET Membership profiles
- your own Db

Answer (score 16):

When I had this problem, it turned out that I had a reference to a dll which had a Settings.settings (or Settings.Designer.cs) file.

What happens is that when editing the Setting.settings file, upon clicking the blank line at the bottom, a new line is added with template information and a default user setting instead of application setting. This is a nice feature but you could see how after changing the template and adding your new setting, then clicking below to lose focus a new template line is added and if you are not paying attention, you accidently add a user setting. Check if you have this file in a referenced dll and remove any user settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can make Application scope settings writable by simply adding a setter to the property definition in `Settings.Designer.cs`.  For instance:

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("AdminContext")]
public string DbContext
{
    get { return ((string)(this["DbContext"])); }
    set { this["DbContext"] = value; } }
```

The caveat is that the `Settings.Designer.cs` is auto-generated, and therefore if you use the designer UI, your setters will be overwritten.

This works in console and web applications.

Comment: Although this is not best practice, it *does* work and is fully tested.  Given I caveat the approach in the body, I don't think it is valid to give a down vote.  This solution is "use at your own risk" but nevertheless, it *is* a solution.

Comment: ***Settings.Designer.cs is auto-generated***. Not good solution.